# Adding struct data breaks calls

Tags: database, postgresql, go, gorp

I'm using gorp and the *DBMap.addTableWithName() function to create tables.

If I have the following:

```
...
type S1 struct {
  Id    int    `db:"id"`
  Name  string `db:"name"`
  Value string `db:"value"`
}

dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.PostgresDialect{}}

dbmap.AddTableWithName(S1{}, "s1Table").SetKeys(true, "Id")

...
```

Which works as expected.

If I modify the struct to this

```
...
type S1 struct {
  Id    int    `db:"id"`
  Name  string `db:"name"`
  Value string `db:"value"`
  Extra string `db:"extra"`
}
...
```

Then the table isnt modified with the new struct structure.

If I modify the database manually

`ALTER TABLE s1Table ADD COLUMN extra text;`

then run any queries I get back 
`sql: Scan error on column index 3, name "extra": converting NULL to string is unsupported`

I've looked through the GoDocs for gorp but nothing has jumped out at me as a solution.

My Question is - is it possible for gorp to manage these table changes? If not then how would it be done to not result in a `converting NULL to string is unsupported` error.

Comment: Try adding Extra as a pointer: Extra *string

Comment: Either alter the column to have the `NOT NULL` constraint and set `DEFAULT ''` for it as well, that way no row in that table will ever have that column be `NULL`. Or, use `sql.NullString`, or `*string` instead of `string` as the type of the `Extra` field.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva - I had been trying to set a default of a blank string as "" not '' (PEBKAC). Do you know how one could manage these sort of changes in gorp? Also, if you change your command to an answer ill mark it as

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have experience with gorp so I do not know how one would handle migrations with it.